# Angular function inside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined an [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) dialog as follows in my *angular-app.js*:

```
angular.module('myAPP', ['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.status = '  ';
    $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev,_url) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            templateUrl: _url,
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true
        }).then(function(answer) {
            $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
        }, function() {
            $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
    };
});

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
}
```

And in my HTML page I have this:

```
<a ng-click="openDetailDialog()">Show details</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDetailDialog(id) {
        var id = getValue(id, 'id');
        showAdvanced($event,'${readDetailURL}&id=' + id + '/');
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I add the function `showAdvanced()` inside another function, it doesn't work.
When I call this function directly in `ng-click`, it works.

This works:

```
<a ng-click="showAdvanced($event,'http:myurl/test/id');">Show details</a>
```

Why?

Comment: Well, there is no bare `function showAdvanced()` defined anywhere. Angular resolves everything against the current scope using its own rules. The long and short of it is: that's simply not how it works.

Comment: @deceze I'm newbie of angularJS, I'm leargning, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well, what you want cannot be done. If it's an Angular function, it cannot be called from plain Javascript. Reformulate your approach/strategy/question.

Answer (score 1):

First you can't attach or bind something that is not on the $scope, or the controller itself.

```html
<a ng-click="openDetailDialog()">Show details</a>
```

**That's wrong.**

And second you can't access variables attached to the scope from plain javascript, 2WDB (two way data binding) just include HTML. And of course angular works with encapsulated scope.

Answer (score -1):

The function ´showAdvanced()`actually is part of the`$scope`element. When you do this in your html:

```
<a ng-click="showAdvanced()">text</a>
```

AngularJs changes that (behind the scenes) to `$scope.showAdvanced()`

If you want to call it from javascript, you could try and change your function call to

```
`$scope.showAdvanced()`
```

Comment: There's no global `$scope` variable you could access from plain Javascript either... It's a bit more involved than that.

Comment: @deceze Ah damned, you're right. I was thinking about a plain javascript code defined within the scope in a js-file, which would work.